# Intellij tomcat Input Console

Tags: console, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a project in Intellij with tomcat server.
In this project I have a thread with a localshell who read console input (System.in).

In Eclipse I can typing in my console and localshell read system.in with no problem.
But in Intellij I have an Output console but not an Input console (screenshot)
When I typing in this console (output console) nothing happens.

Can you help me ?

[IntellijConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAPgD.png)

Thanks

Comment: Why did you add console input exactly?

Comment: To manipulate some data easly and dynamically (put message in file mq, read database....)

Comment: You can trigger those from HTTP. That’s what Tomcat’s for.